# Anyway to Authenticate a user using Google Apps in an Android application?

Tags: android, authentication, google-apps

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way I can Authenticate a Google Apps User in a Android Application?

One approach I know of is to take could take their username and password in a android view, and use the clientLogin interface (http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html).

However I was wondering if there was a different approach, maybe pushing to a browser window where it would show the google login for that domain, but I would not know how to get the details back to the application, after the authentication is done.

Any ideas on how it would be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also try using OAuth.  It's supported by Google Apps, and has a [Java client library](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/).

Answer (score 6):

I wrote up how to get a google auth token from android (works fine in any java really) so you can call app engine hosted web services as an authenticated google user:

http://javagwt.blogspot.com/2009/12/authenticating-android-app-to-google.html

hope this helps